# Is it possible to customize OAuth error responses in WSO2 Identity Server using a Custom Identity Event Handler?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working with WSO2 Identity Server and trying to enhance the customization of OAuth error responses. I've come across the concept of a Custom Identity Event Handler, and I am wondering if it's possible to leverage this mechanism to tailor OAuth error responses based on specific events.

In particular, I want to handle events such as "PostAuthenticationFailed" and "PostAuthorizationFailed" during OAuth grants. My goal is to dynamically construct OAuthProblemException instances and include additional fields in the error response.

Here is a sample code snippet of what I have in mind:

```
  // Get the event name
  String eventName = event.getEventName();

  // Initialize a List<Map<String, Object>> to store additional fields
  List<Map<String, Object>> additionalFields = new ArrayList<>();

  if (eventName.equals("PostAuthenticationFailed")) {
    // Get the specific authentication error (replace with actual error retrieval logic)
    String authenticationError = getAuthenticationError(event);

    // Construct custom OAuth error response
    OAuthProblemException customException = new OAuthProblemException();
    customException.setError("custom_auth_error");
    customException.setErrorDescription("Authentication failed");

    // Add authentication error to additional fields
    Map<String, Object> authErrorField = new HashMap<>();
    authErrorField.put("field", "authentication_error");
    authErrorField.put("value", authenticationError);
    additionalFields.add(authErrorField);

    // Set the custom response on the event
    event.setProcessingFailed(true);
    event.addParameter("error", customException);

  } else if (eventName.equals("PostAuthorizationFailed")) {
    // Get the specific authorization error (replace with actual error retrieval logic)
    String authorizationError = getAuthorizationError(event);

    // Construct custom OAuth error response
    OAuthProblemException customException = new OAuthProblemException();
    customException.setError("custom_authz_error");
    customException.setErrorDescription("Authorization failed");

    // Add authorization error to additional fields
    Map<String, Object> authzErrorField = new HashMap<>();
    authzErrorField.put("field", "authorization_error");
    authzErrorField.put("value", authorizationError);
    additionalFields.add(authzErrorField);

    // Set the custom response on the event
    event.setProcessingFailed(true);
    event.addParameter("error", customException);
  }

  // Add the additional fields to the event
  event.addParameter("additional_fields", additionalFields);
}

// Example methods for retrieving specific errors (replace with actual implementation)
private String getAuthenticationError(Event event) {
  // Replace with logic to retrieve authentication error
  return "invalid_credentials";
}

private String getAuthorizationError(Event event) {
  // Replace with logic to retrieve authorization error
  return "insufficient_permissions";
}
```

Is this approach feasible, and if so, are there any specific considerations or best practices to keep in mind when implementing such a customization?